# Do I need a transit visa for transit flight from Vienna to New Delhi for Indian citizens?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, transit

I am traveling from USA to India via Vienna, Austria in June 1st week of 2015. I am having a valid I-797 valid until Dec 2016 and also EAD documents. However I don't have valid USA visa now because I did not go out of USA for last 8 years.

I have a layover of around 4.5 hrs in Vienna on my way to India. Do I need any kind of transit visa in Vienna. I am not planning to go anywhere outside the waiting area of international travel lounge. Please advise.

I hold Indian Passport and valid USA EAD documents.

Comment: I called Austrian consulate in NY city (Ph: 212 933 5149) and confirmed with them that I don't need the transit visa in this case.

Answer (score -1):

No.

```
Information as of  14MAY15 / 2002 UTC
National India (IN)             /Embarkation USA (US)
Transit Austria (AT)            /Destination India (IN)
ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
Austria (AT)

TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets in transit
.
*Note: TWOV is not possible when arriving from
a non-Schengen Member State AND departing to a Schengen Member

Austria (AT)
Vaccinations not required.

(snipped)
```